# Как загрузить html файл из сети в приложение, чтоб потом смотреть его оффлайн?

Tags: java, android, html, http, url

Как загрузить html файл из сети в приложение, чтоб потом смотреть его оффлайн?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите иметь больше контроля на кэшем, Вы можете просто скачать локально копию HTML-страницы и затем показать её (пример кода ниже).

Плюс такого подхода в том, что бы можете получить доступ к кэшированой копии где угодно в приложении. Она останется между запусками приложения, и Вы сами можете удалить или обновить её когда захотите.

Минус в том, что Вам надо будет самому узнавать, не изменился ли файл на сервере и не требуется ли обновить кэшированную копию.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onDoClick(View view) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, File>() {

            @Override
            protected File doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String fileName = "test.html";
                String urlToDownload = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683391/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD";
                File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir(), fileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                    FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), fileStream);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //TODO: Log exception
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (connection != null) {
                            connection.disconnect();
                        }
                        if (fileStream != null) {
                            try {
                                fileStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return file;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(File file) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.loadUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

На активити только конпка и веб-вью

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/doButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onDoClick"
        android:text="Do stuff" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/doButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`IOUtils.copy` -- это часть библиотек [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), их использовать не обязательно, Вы можете скопировать данные и по старинке с помощью буфера, пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854211/android-store-inputstream-in-file). Использование анонимной `AsyncTask` прямо вот так в обработчике клика не лучшая идея, здесь это исключительно для упрощения примера.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень выручили)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет закэшировать, потом проверять сеть и подгружать в зависимости от интернета

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5*1024*1024);

//если есть интернет
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
//иначе
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ. 
Если Вы знает, то скажите пожалуйста, в каком месте указать url, тот самый откуда их выкачивать?
И если, этих файлов много, то как лучше будет организовать выкачку.
И при дестрое активности, данные не очистятся(извините за такой вопрос)

Спасибо